# What does &lt;/p&gt; mean in query results?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok, I run a simple query,

```
SELECT description 
FROM TABLE
WHERE id = 111;
```

in my results, I get:

```
&lt;p&gt;Blah blah description is here blah blah&lt;p&gt;
```

Then when I output my results with PHP using:

```
echo '<ul>' . $row['description'] . '</ul>';
```

I get this on my html page:

```
<p>Blah blah description is here blah blah</p>
```

How can I get rid of the `<p>` tags at the beginning and end of my description? I am using concrete5 for my page if that helps.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it was inserted by concrete5.

Comment: You've got encoded html entities in your text, e.g. you've stored html in encoded form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) to get rid of HTML.

```
$string = "&lt;p&gt;Blah blah description is here blah blah&lt;p&gt;";
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
$string = strip_tags($string);
echo $string; // Blah blah description is here blah blah
```

You shouldn't typically store HTML in the database though. Unless the input is coming from a source like a WYSIWYG you will want to store plaintext. This smells like a case where plaintext was needed.

Comment: That fixed it.  I didn't create the DB but the description is entered through an online form using a text box I believe.  Maybe thats whats was causing the html entities to be stored in BD.  Oh well, its fixed now and I learned something! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

Those are encoded html entities. to get rid of them you may do this:

```
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($yourString));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode($var))
```

or

```
htmlentities(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($var)))
```

work for me